# Integration of angular 2 with JAVA EE

Tags: java, angular, jakarta-ee, eclipse-neon

I want to integrate angular 2 with Java in eclipse Neon EE version . I don't know how to integrate these both under single dynamic web project? In short angular 2 should be front end and JAVA should be backend. I need to know to basic steps to create a dynamic web project with these two.

I already have :
NPM - 4.2.0
CLI - 1.1.1
JAVA - 1.8
Neon - 4.6.0

Comment: If you know how to add static files that must be served by your webapp, then you know how to integrate an angular app built with the CLI. You build the angular app (with ng build), then put all the files under `dist` inside the Java EE application.

Comment: so basically i need to make two projects. One will be dynamic web project say DWP and another will be angular project say AP. Now i have to build the AP and put it under webapp folder of DWP.
Where is this **dist** folder i can't find it?

Comment: It's created by Angular CLI when running ng build.

Comment: [This link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/angular-cli/overview/) may help you to know how to use Angular CLI

Comment: Thanks for reply @JB. I have added .dist folder under WebContent folder of my dyanamic web project. Now if i ran the the project on tomcat server nothing is happening

Comment: Thanks for reply @AnassB. But it was not telling anything about how to configure the dynamic web project to run.

Comment: After installing Angular CLI, you can use the command `ng new your_project` to create your angular project. You may run after that `ng serve` on the root of the created project to build the application and make it available on `http://localhost:4200`

Comment: @AnassB. yes that thing i know but where does Java come into action. Where Java code will be present. For example, if i want to do a DB interaction i need to use JAVA, where will this come from and how will i access that java code??

Comment: I. If you choose use 2 separate projects: You can develop your backend code in a Java project using a Restful webservice API, and then access your exposed data from your Angular project using HTTP calls. II. If you want to use one project: The `ng build` generates javascript, css and html files into the dist folder. These files can be hosted within the same folder where Java classes and libraries will be published (Note that you must still expose your data using webservices or a servlet URL to/from which you can request the back end logic)